# clearcase branch type property in command line

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Can you please help with cleartool command which can display following of branch type.

```
 State -->  Locked, Unlocked, or Obsolete. 
 Locked by 
 Locked on 
 Description
 Excluded users
```

One of the task what i'm trying to do is add few more admin users to excluded list...(need excluded users list to append and send that input to lock command with -replace and -nusers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be:

```
cleartool lslock brtype:aBranch@\aPVob
```

(see [`cleartool lslock` man page](https://www.google.com/search?q=cleartool%20lslock%20site%3aibm.com&oq=cleartool%20lslock%20site%3aibm.com&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

That would displayed the excluded users you need for you to append one more, and pass it to a `cleartool lock -nusers` command.